# How to publish a part of repo?

Tags: git

I have a project which structure is following:
source/
../dir1/
../../file1  <- make public
../../file1
../dir3/  <- make public
../dir4/
One of my colleagues asked me to share a part of code, which is mark as "make public".

So how one export partially repo, so public repository would look like:
source/
../../file1
../dir3/

The only solution i thought is to make a copy, then remove all private files and dirs.
But then i would need to do so again and again once a new commit in initial repo is done.

Is there more elegant way?

Comment: Yes, write a script that exports files (without history) and removes the private directories just like your are currently doing by hand…

Comment: `git archive` will be your friend, take a look on the examples https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html

Comment: As far as i know `git archive` makes a .tar file out of whole repo, whether i need only specific dirs and files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to partially export a git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540565/how-to-partially-export-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [git-filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).

For the sake of simplicity, I'll use a slightly abridged version of your case.

Let's say you have a project with 2 directory:

- `private`, which you want to remove from history
- `public`, that you want to preserve.

Since we are going to rewrite the history and purge objects from the repository, **make a copy of it**: you won't be able to recover the lost data.

Now, run

> **`git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch private/*' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`**

This will delete every reference to `private` in each commit.

- with **`--index-filter`** you can define the filter to execute. In our case, `git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch private/*` will remove from the index the content of the directory `private`
- **`--tag-name-filter cat`** is an idiomatic git expression to rewrite tags (see the obscure man page about this option). Note that tag signatures will be stripped.
- it's possible that the application of the filter will produce some empty commits. The option **`--prune-empty`** will remove them.
- **`--all`** just tells git to apply the filter to all the commits.